# jQuery UI Slider + Rails + SimpleForm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, simple-form

I'm trying to insert a [jQuery UI Slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/) within [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) in Rails 3.2.

I create a new input class `app/inputs/slider_input.rb`

```
class SliderInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base
  def input
    "<div class='slider-input'></div>#{@builder.hidden_field(attribute_name, input_html_options)}"
  end
end
```

Here the `_form.html.erb`

```
<%= simple_form_for(@post, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :rating, :as => :slider, :input_html => { :value => '6' } %>
  <%= f.input :telephone %>
  <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'pull-right' %>
<% end %>
```

The problem is that the generated code is:

```
<div class="controls">
<div class="slider-input ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <a href="#" class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all"></a>
</div>
<input type="hidden" value="10" name="post[rating]" id="post_rating" class="slider required"></div>
```

How can I pass the default value `6` in the hidden field? Currently the default is 10, dunno why, probably for the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".slider-input").slider({
            min: 1,
            max: 10,
            values: [ 6 ],
            step: 0.5,
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                $(this).next('input').val(ui.value);
                $(this).parent().find('span.slider-value').html(ui.value);
            }
    });
});
```

Also, is it the best way to achieve a custom slider input? I'm sorry but I'm a Rails novice.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're just initializing the slider incorrectly, using `values` instead of `value`.

Here's how you set one value:

```
$( ".selector" ).slider({ value: 10 });
```

And here's how you set multiple values:

```
$( ".selector" ).slider({ values: [ 10, 25 ] });
```

Have a look at the [jquery API](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-value) docs for more documentation on setting the value.